# doPost super causing - HTTP Status 405

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-405

Till now I believed it was a common practice to call a `super.doPost(req, resp)` from your servlet's `doPost(req, resp){}` 
But here's the issue I faced -
I have a very simple servlet having a doPost(req, resp) and since it was auto generated method from eclipse it was having `super.doPost(req, resp)` which is fine as it is calling its parent's doPost() but I was getting

> HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
>   whenever the servlet was hit.
>   I went through a lot of post and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105584/http-status-405-http-method-get-is-not-supported-by-this-url)

had been talking about the same issue and one of the solution suggested was remove the super.doGet().

I did the same with my Post method and to my surprise it worked!!!!

I cannot find a logical reason for this. Can someone please explain what was happening?
Why was

> 405
>   flashing due to call of super.doPost().

Thanks,
Saurabh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default implementation of `HttpServlet.doPost` returns a 405 error (method not allowed). You have to implement the `doPost` method if you want to support the POST method in your servlet.

This is the [code of `HttpServlet.doPost`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29):

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    String protocol = req.getProtocol();
    String msg = lStrings.getString("http.method_post_not_supported");
    if (protocol.endsWith("1.1")) {
        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, msg);
    } else {
        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: So we extend the HttpServlet and @Override doPost but in our implementation we don't call its super since call to the super will give this message. Hmmm.... After reading your reply I also went through [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244785/when-not-to-call-super-method-when-overriding).                                                   Got It!!!