# Is there a difference between calling a supermethod and not implementing?

Tags: java, inheritance

In the following example, the call `FirstChildclass first; first.someMethod();` will do the same as `SecondChildclass second; second.someMethod();`. Or am I wrong?

```
class Superclass {
   public void someMethod() {
      //do something
   }
}

class FirstChildclass extends Superclass {

   @Override
   public void someMethod() {
      super.someMethod();
   }

   public void someOtherMethod() {
      //do something else
   }
}

class SecondChildclass extends Superclass {

   public void someOtherMethod() {
      //do something else
   }
}
```

Is there a reason why one will implement it like in `FirstChildclass`? Because I have seen many implementations like in `FistChildclass` and am wondering why anyone would do it.

Comment: Try to write it and run it

Comment: "child" classes don't seem to implement or extend anything

Comment: That is exactly the question. If I just want the logic of super method. Why would I write it in the way of `FirstChildclass`?

Comment: @emi-le yes, why would you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When NOT to call super() method when overriding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244785/when-not-to-call-super-method-when-overriding)

Comment: It only makes sense if it's a constructor.

Comment: btw, your child clases do not actually extend `SuperClass`

Comment: I can only guess. It is code generated using code generation / refactoring functionality of an IDE; it is not the product of actual thought.

Comment: dude, in your question you even hasn't any inheritance between your classes :( so this code will not compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ask about the difference between:

```
@Override
public returnType someName() {
    return super.someName();
}
```

and not overriding it. There is no difference as well as there is no sense in doing it.

You should call `super.someName()` just in case you want to extend the original method.

**Watch out!** If you have a constructor you want to use in a child class, but you don't need any additional behavior, you'll call `super(arguments)`.

Comment: void method can't return anything

Comment: TY, xenteros. I was of the same opinion, but wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

This is about your design. Override means you wanna change the already existing implementation which is inherited from the parent.
If you are not doing anything different then you don;t want to do the

```
@Override
public void someMethod() {
      super.someMethod();
}
```

That is useless.

```
@Override
public void someMethod() {
   // do some other logic
   super.someMethod();
   // do some other logic
}
```

This is perfectly ok :) Because you are doing some tasks other than the parent's implementation.

Comment: why i get -1 for this?

Comment: This is correct. However, be aware that this can sometimes be a sign of poor design (in the base class or derived class or both).

Comment: Yeah I agree, this might lose the original concept of override

Comment: `unless parent class is abstract and the method is abstract.`---better delete this part. It might be the reason for the downvote.